# How to apply to_datetime or with sort_index so that the dates are sorted?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I don't know how to apply to_datetime, because the output of the dates are not sorted.

```
In [16]: df[('JAS','ask')][:6]
Out[16]: 
2013-02-01    118.6400
2013-03-01    123.1600
2012-08-01    104.0200
2012-11-01    108.6600
2013-01-02    114.8800
2013-04-02    125.9700
Name: (JAS, ask), dtype: object
```

The below is my code, and the last line have already use to_datetime with format, and I have tried sort_index but the result still failed:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

dat = json.load(open('pruItems.json'))
frames = [] 
keys=[]
for d in dat:
    if d['data']:
        frame = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d['data'], columns=['date', 'bid' ,'ask'])
        frame.set_index('date', inplace=True)
        frames.append(frame)
        keys.append(d['fund'])
df = pd.concat(frames, axis=1, keys=keys)

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Enclosed please find the link of my json file:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1UY10-kbb4YYU5KYXllOVNYbnc/edit?usp=sharing

The data sample is as following:
    db = {u'data': [[u'18/06/2013', u'34.8400', u'34.8400'],
      [u'17/06/2013', u'34.4900', u'34.4900']],
      u'fund': u'TGC'},
    {u'data': [[u'18/06/2013', u'14.9179', u'14.9179'],
     [u'17/06/2013', u'14.8712', u'14.8712']],
     u'fund': u'FEF'},
    {u'data': [[u'18/06/2013', u'6.6780', u'6.6780'],
     [u'17/06/2013', u'6.6510', u'6.6570']],
     u'fund': u'FAF'}]

Comment: to_datetime doesn't require any sorted-ness.

Comment: Then, what part of df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d/%m/%Y') is incorrect that the output dates are not sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) *after* the index are (converted to) dates:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
                TGC               FEF              FAF
                bid      ask      bid      ask     bid     ask
date
18/06/2013  34.8400  34.8400  14.9179  14.9179  6.6780  6.6780
17/06/2013  34.4900  34.4900  14.8712  14.8712  6.6510  6.6570

In [12]: df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
                TGC               FEF              FAF
                bid      ask      bid      ask     bid     ask
2013-06-18  34.8400  34.8400  14.9179  14.9179  6.6780  6.6780
2013-06-17  34.4900  34.4900  14.8712  14.8712  6.6510  6.6570

In [14]: df.sort_index()  # you can also do this inplace=True
Out[14]:
                TGC               FEF              FAF
                bid      ask      bid      ask     bid     ask
2013-06-17  34.4900  34.4900  14.8712  14.8712  6.6510  6.6570
2013-06-18  34.8400  34.8400  14.9179  14.9179  6.6780  6.6780
```